# Initialize Blob storage in Startup.cs

Tags: c#, blob, azure-blob-storage

I have two different storage accounts. I need to get a blob from a different storage account & container and then push a response after an API call to a container of another storage account.

I need help on how to initialize the same storage class for different storage accounts and keys.
How to make `_accountName` and `_storageKey` generic in the below code?

```
private async Task<CloudBlockBlob> GetBlockBlob(string containerName, string blockName)
{
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(
        new StorageCredentials(_accountName, _storageKey), true);
    var blobContainer = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient().GetContainerReference(containerName);
    await blobContainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
    return blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(blockName);
}
```

Comment: Do you want to send data from one storage to another? or you want to select a storage account based on user request?

Answer (score 0):

You should save **both the values** of `_accountName` and `_storageKey` in **App settings**. Then, you can create global variables for both storage accounts. For example:

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount1 = new CloudStorageAccount(
                    new StorageCredentials(_accountName1, _storageKey1), true);

CloudStorageAccount storageAccount2 = new CloudStorageAccount(
                    new StorageCredentials(_accountName2, _storageKey2), true);
```

Then, you can have two methods for fetching Blobs like below:

```
private async Task<CloudBlockBlob> GetBlockBlobFrom1(string containerName, string blockName)
        {
            var blobContainer = storageAccount1.CreateCloudBlobClient().GetContainerReference(containerName);
            await blobContainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
            return blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(blockName);
        }

private async Task<CloudBlockBlob> GetBlockBlobFrom2(string containerName, string blockName)
        {
            var blobContainer = storageAccount2.CreateCloudBlobClient().GetContainerReference(containerName);
            await blobContainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
            return blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(blockName);
        }
```

Comment: Does this help?